# Assign image array to string

Tags: python

I want to assign my image names to another string. Below I have described the problem.

```
num=[10,20,30,40,50,60,.....500]
for i in range(len(num)):
  img[i]=str(num[i])+'_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
```

so after this loop it should give me,

```
img0='10_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
img1='20_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
....
img499='500_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
```

this means, img0 equal the image name of 10_image_plane_XX_YY.fits, img1 equal the image name of 20_image_plane_XX_YY.fits, etc. So I just need to use img0, img1,..for my corresponding images in further analysis.
But, when I run this loop, it gives me following error

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Please let me know any sollution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

-Viral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I think you are trying to do, a list comprehension seems like the more natural approach.

```
num=[10,20,30,40,50,60]  # I truncated your array for brevity
img = [str(i)+'_image_plane_XX_YY.fits' for i in num]
```

This will construct `img` as an array with your assembled strings.  For example:

```
>>> num=[10,20,30,40,50,60]
>>> img = [str(i)+'_image_plane_XX_YY.fits' for i in num]
>>> img[0]
'10_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
>>> img[3]
'40_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
```

Comment: Thanks rchang. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one reason for this: your `img` is a string.

This err msg means: strings are immutable, so you can't change their characters in-place.

I think you `img` should be a list or something similar. Plz check your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `img[i]`, since you're trying to assign a string to string index and - as the error tells you - strings don't support item assignment.

You can use a dict instead:

```
img = {}
num=[10,20,30,40,50,60,.....500]
for i in range(len(num)):
   img[i]=str(num[i])+'_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
```

So that img becomes:

```
{ 0:'10_image_plane_XX_YY.fits', 
  1: '20_image_plane_XX_YY.fits',
  ....
  499: '500_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
}
```

and you can call images name as:

```
>>> img[0]
'10_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'

>>> img[1]
'20_image_plane_XX_YY.fits'
```

However, if you don't need anything other than an integer as key, you should probably use list comprehension as [suggested by rchang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28830567/2926113).